# rails 3: How can I concatenate a number to a symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, recursion

I would like the `@comment1` to change to `@comment2` by using the `i` in the 1..5 loop. I have the following code that is pretty repetitive. I am hoping to dry it up.

Hi,I am using acts_as_commentable_with_threading. I am basically looping through all comments and checking to see if that comment has children. If so, print out the children while checking to see if those children have children. So I plan on going a few levels deep, hence the @comment1,2,3, etc...How can I DRY this? Recursion some how? If not, I could maybe go a few levels deep and end the comment indentation at @comment5 for example.

## EDIT!

Thank you Samiron!

Here is the updated helper function...

```
    def show_comments_with_children(comments)
    
     comments.each do |comment|
         
         yield comment
         if comment.children.any?
           concat <<-EOF.html_safe
                <div class="span7 offset1-1 pcomment">
           EOF
            show_comments_with_children(comment.children) {                 |x| yield  x } #Dont worry, this will not run another query :)
               concat <<-EOF.html_safe
                    </div>
               EOF
         end   
     end
  end
```

---

```
<div class="span7 offset1-1 pcomment">
<% @comment1 = comment.children%>
<% for comment in @comment1 %>
 <%= render "comment_replies", :comment => comment %>
            
<div class="span7 offset1-1 pcomment">
<% @comment2 = comment.children%>
<% for comment in @comment2 %>
<%= render "comment_replies", :comment => comment %>

<div class="span7 offset1-1 pcomment">
<% @comment3 = comment.children%>
<% for comment in @comment3 %>
<%= render "comment_replies", :comment => comment %>

                <% end %>
            </div>
```

....

```
<%(1..5).each do |i| %>
  <% @comment1 = comment.children%>
  <% for comment in @comment1 %>
    <%= render "comment_replies", :comment => comment %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "`@comment1` to change to `@comment2` by using the `i`"?

Comment: My view has a lot of repetitive code and I am trying to dry things up. I am working on printing out threaded comments. I have this in my view that keeps repeating...

Comment: This is a code smell, if you have a series of ivars used for the same purpose, you should consider using one hash or array instead.

Comment: Isn't this code just printing the same thing 8 times?

Comment: Maybe its not the actual code.

Comment: What happens if you have more than 5 comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are looking for `instance_variable_set`.

```
# Following snippet is not TESTED. It is here to just demonstrate "instance_variable_set"
<%(1..5).each do |i| %>
  <% instance_variable_set("@comment#{i}", comment.children) %>
  <% for comment in instance_variable_get("@comment#{i}") %>
    <%= render "comment_replies", :comment => comment %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But definitely this is **not a recommendable approach**. You can share your controller code and what you want to achieve in your view. There must be some way to make it properly DRY. In your post you are always getting `comment.children`. is it really?

---

### Actual Solution:

Your view code will be like this

```
#0th level is the top level
<% show_comments_with_children(@comments, 0) do |comment, level|%>
   <!-- #Use level to differ the design for different depth-->
   <%= render "comment_replies", :comment => comment %>
<%end%>
```

and add this helper function `show_comments_with_children` in your helper function. Which will be.

```
def show_comments_with_children(comments, level)
   comments.each do |comment|
       yield comment, level
       if comment.children.any?
           show_comments_with_children(comment.children, level+1) {|x, l| yield x, l} #Dont worry, this will not run another query :)
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: the yield is not working properly. Actually the block need to be passed. I will be back with right code shortly.

Comment: Updated... Hope now it will work as expected. Let us know the status :)

Comment: Hi, The code works and I am really thankful! I have one minor issue that I can't seem to figure out. Where can I insert this div "  <div class="span7 offset1-1 comment">". This div would encapsulate children/s and then end the div when there are no more children. I am thinking it should belong in the helper.

Comment: If it is always `<div class="span7 offset1-1 pcomment">` then your code should work. It seems is already enclosing your children of a comment. However, it can be a bit cleaner by `concat '<div class="span7 offset1-1 pcomment">'.html_safe`. BUT If it is not then please add the exact html that you want as output.

Answer (score 0):

The manor in which you are defining this code is rather poor, and you should consider defining `@comment` as an array rather than as independent variables for each `@comment1, @comment2, etc.`.

That said, what you are looking for is the `instance_variable_get()` method

```
<(1..5).each do |i| %>
  <% instance_variable_set("@comment#{i}", comment.children) %>
  <% for comment in instance_variable_get("@comment#{i}") %>
    <%= render "comment_replies", :comment => comment %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is definitely something good to know but in this case I highly recommend converting you comment instance variables to an array!